# Aptana 3 - Any way to save file sets?

Tags: aptana

Sometimes I work in Aptana on several projects at the same time and having 10 files open for one project and 7 files open for a different project can be confusing. Is there any way to save these as "file sets" (or something!)?
It would be really handy to chose your project and then have Aptana open the files that you were working on but only for the selected project?

Does this functionality exist in Aptana 3?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that functionality exists in Aptana per se. However, there is an Eclipse plugin-in called Mylyn that does, essentially, what you're after. Mylyn (http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/) is a task management plugin and one of its best features is that you can create contexts for tasks, where a context is the set of files and folders you are accessing or using for that particular task.

Let's say that in Project A, you create a task called "Enable User Authentication" (i.e., build a freaking login component). Once created, you can activate that task and then assign/select as many files and folders as you wish. Whenever you switch to work on that task, your Project Explorer view in Eclipse/Aptana will only show the files and folders related to that task. The files and folders assigned for a task are called the "Context" in Mylyn ... here's a link to the User Guide: http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Mylyn/User_Guide.

Sorry if my reply is choppy ... it's early here in the Rocky Mountains :). That said, do check out Mylyn (or other task management plugins for Eclipse/Aptana). I think this will get you what you, basically, need and help your workflow a lot!

Comment: Sir, you are a star. That is exactly what I was looking for :). Thank you.